# Custom Controller

Tags: odata, servicestack, breeze

So if we get back a LINQ expression tree through Breeze / OData, what examples are there of people interpreting this for cases which are not standard SQL / EF, preferably in a ServiceStack context.

Trying to discover what is in the works or already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a lot of examples yet except for the **NoDb** sample in the breeze zip. But we are actively working on getting some out over the next month or so.

We are looking at adding support for ServiceStack but for now you might want to try using an Web Api ApiController class to start with. The [BreezeController] attribute that you can apply to your ApiController class provides all of the expression tree heavy lifting needed to compose the breeze client side query filters together with your controller methods IQueryable result.

This means that any "webApi" ApiController simply needs to express its endpoints as IQueryable where the breeze client has some metadata about type T.  This metadata can be supplied either client side or server side.  ( I'd start with client side for now, we will have a better NonEF server metadata story in a few weeks).

There is no requirement for either SQL or EF. In fact we are working on Raven and MongoDb examples now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Feel free to ping the [ServiceStack mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/servicestack) if you need any help Integrating Breeze with ServiceStack.